# Angular.js Limit Results / Search All

Tags: jquery, angularjs, performance

Using Angular.js

Database has about 8000 results.  Table takes around 3-10 seconds to load, depending on internet connection.

All results are loaded. Is there a way to limit to say 1000 results, but the search feature load all?  Or does angular have a server side loading?

The app.js is pretty default:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('submit/getJobs.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 100; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

The table row is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">
```

Excuse my ignorance in this.  If you need more code, or something else, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not paginate on the server side. You should limit the returned results in your server, try something like this:

```
$http.get('submit/getJobs.php?currentPage=1&pageSize=100').success(function(data){
    $scope.list = data;
    $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
    $scope.entryLimit = 100; //max no of items to display in a page
    $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
});
```

After that you keep asking the server for more results, incrementing the currentPage querystring.